# Routing with params in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a route

```
my.local/en/auth?code=bla-bla
```

I write in router

```
{path: "/:lang/auth?code=:code" }
```

But it's not working. Then I try other route:

```
{path: "/:lang/auth" }
```

And it's working. So my question is why I can't bind route with get params?

Comment: That's not supported this way. What do you actually try to accomplish?

Comment: I just want know why my route doesn't work.

Comment: Because it's not supported that way.

Answer (score 0):

Different from Angular 1, you do not need to define optional routing parameters for Angular 2.

For you case, you can define

```
{path: "/:lang/auth" }
```

then you can navigate using Router

```
_router.navigate(['/en/auth', { code: 'bla-bla' }])
```

this should redirect you to

```
my.local/en/auth;code=bla-bla
```

Comment: Other service make redirect on this page =)